# How to recognize a click on a drawn rectangle on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, mouse

Say we drawed multiple rectangles in a html5 canvas:

```
    context.fillStyle='black';
    context.fillStroke='black';
    context.beginPath();
for(var i=0; i<50; i++)
{  
    context.rect(i*20,i*20,w,h);
//this is just some random configuration for the rectangles, it doesn't really matter how they are positioned
}
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
```

How can I make it so it's recognizable when the user click on an individual rectangle and then, say, change it's color?

Is it possible or will I have to make a function that takes the mouse x and y coordinates and then check where it landed compared to the x and y coordinates of the rectangles, to finally find the one that "covers" the mouse coordinates?

Comment: Take a look at the hit test in this (possibly duplicate) stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176968/how-to-change-mouse-over-to-onclick/15179322#15179322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it would be better to keep track of the rectangles inside an array and just loop through them to see if it's inside. 
As stated [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880302/4577762):

> When you draw to a canvas element, you are simply drawing a bitmap in
>   immediate mode.
>
> The elements (shapes, lines, images) that are drawn have no
>   representation besides the pixels they use and their colour.[...]

Here comes the **BUT**: I found this [Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13106472/4577762)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of recognizing the click that way. But I guess the other way, by taking the click coordinates is more efficient, since it will make operations only if the user clicks, differently to listening for clicks constantly.

Comment: Also, if you are going to use the list of rectangles, make sure you check for the correct one if they have some parts covered by another ;D. @Vic